# How Can I Create a Custom Splitter implementation in Spring Integration?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration

I'm using Spring Integration and I have some very messy data that needs to be handled/split in a specific way. I need to create a custom splitter for my integration flow. What are some good resources to start implementing custom components with spring integration ? I have been looking at the Spring Boot/Integration documentation and the actual backend code but have not found good resources to learn how to implement custom components ( I'm sure it's out there and I'm probably looking in the wrong place). I did find two stackoverflow posts describing how to implement a custom splitter for a csv file which was useful but did not help me in understanding how the underlying technology works so that I can implement my own for any situation. A simple, generic example would be helpful.

[Spring Integration: Custom Splitter with Header Enrichment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44604817/spring-integration-custom-splitter-with-header-enrichment)

[How to create custom component and add it to flow in spring java dsl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31626497/how-to-create-custom-component-and-add-it-to-flow-in-spring-java-dsl)

Comment: Would you mind sharing more what is your business goal? Let's see if you really need to implement an `AbstractMessageSplitter` or just plain POJO method invocation is enough for you. The Java DSL allows this `split(Object service, String methodName)` and docs explain it as a call to a method of some service which could return something iterable: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/message-routing.html#splitter. `Stream` and `Flux` are also supported types to be splitted.

Comment: So an external API is sending me a response back after I call it. The expected response type is in json format which I have modeled as a POJO. The response back can contain up to 10K records in the json array and I want to package each element of that list as a message to send to a service activator/handler.

Comment: So, just build a `Stream` of those records and return it from a POJO method call. Doesn't look like an internal API of Spring Integration has to be involved somehow...

Comment: ok, I guess I was over complicating the problem. Thanks Artem!